# Rails search - including multiple tables in the same index search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I am a beginner struggling to get the search function working on my rails app.   I have two objects - user and profile.   I want to be able to search across properties that exist in either the user or profile, in this case, the email and last name.

I'm currently getting this error:

`SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: last_name: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (last_name LIKE '%test')`

Here's my code:

**Schema**

```
create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "job_title"
    t.string   "phone_number"
    t.string   "contact_email"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.integer  "plan_id"
    t.string   "stripe_customer_token"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   
   def index
      @users = User.includes(:profile).map{ |user| user.profile }.flatten

      if params[:search]
         @users = User.includes(:profile).search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
      else
         @users = User.all.order('created_at DESC')
      end
   end
   
   # GET request made to /users/:id
   def show
    @user = User.find( params[:id] )
   end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
has_one :profile 

def self.search(search)
    where("email LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
    where("last_name LIKE ?", "%#{search}")
end
```

**profile.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="search">
                 <br/>
                 <div class="md-form mt-0">
                     <%= form_tag(users_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
                    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search profiles" %>
                    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
                
            </div> 
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <% @users.each do |user| %>
                    <% if user.profile %>
                        <li>
                            <div class="well row <%= cycle('white-bg', '') %>">
                                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                                    <% if user.profile.avatar %>
                                        <%= link_to user do %>
                                        <%= image_tag user.profile.avatar.url, class: 'user-index-avatar' %>
                                        <% end %>
                                    <% end %>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <%= link_to user do %>
                                    <h2><%= user.profile.first_name %> <%=user.profile.last_name%></h2>
                                    <% end %>
                                    <p><%= user.profile.job_title %></p>
                                    <p><%= user.profile.description %></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I've tried many different variations of the search method body. I've tried includes and joins functions, but nothing seems to be working. When I comment out this part:

```
where("last_name LIKE ?", "%#{search}")
```

It works by search via email address.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the problem is that you have to specify which table you are querying at.  You should probably do something like this:

```
@user = User.joins(:profile)
            .where('users.email LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
            .where('profiles.last_name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was mostly spot on.  I updated it to: 
```@user = User.joins(:profile)
            .where('users.email LIKE ? OR profiles.last_name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%","%#{search}%")```

I also had to update ```users.DESC``` in the users controller and it worked.  Thanks again!